# Inconsistent notifications watching files with Google Drive REST API V3

Tags: rest, google-drive-api

I'm using this endpoint to subscribe for changes on a file: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/watch. While I'm receiving callbacks, some notifications don't happen right away and others seem to be dropped completely. I'm trying to figure out whether this is an issue with the service or something I'm not understanding about the API.

I've tried testing our setup with several different types of files and have gotten similar results with inconsistent notifications.

Wonder if anyone has done tests or has insider information about the reliability of change notifications? Is it around 99% or more like 50%? What is the expected distribution of delays? (it's definitely not instantaneous)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what you have already done, I can only suggest that you check [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) and see if you've missed  some of the important things.

It was discussed that, to use push notifications, you need to do three things:

> - [Register the domain](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#registering-your-domain) of your receiving URL.
> - Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
> - Set up a [notification channel](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push#creating-notification-channels) for each resource endpoint you want to watch.

In addition to that, note that there are required properties when making watch requests:

> - An id property string that uniquely identifies this new notification channel within your project. We recommend that you use a universally unique identifier (UUID) or any similar unique string.
> - A type property string set to the value web_hook.
> - An address property string set to the URL that listens and responds to notifications for this notification channel. This is your Webhook callback URL, and it must use HTTPS.

Also, Drive API will be able to send notifications to this HTTPS address only if there is a valid SSL certificate installed on your web server. Invalid certificates include:

- Self-signed certificates.
- Certificates signed by an untrusted source.
- Certificates that have been revoked.
- Certificates that have a subject that doesn't match the target hostname.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Teyam. I think the fact that I'm receiving any callbacks at all rules out most of the configuration problems you pointed out here. My problem is that some notifications are delayed and some notifications are missing, not that the setup isn't working at all. Your answer did me go back and clarify the question though!

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I see that this post is nearly a year old.  Did you ever learn anything more, @yayitswei?

Comment: I am still having the same problem.

Comment: @yayitswei Got something? Same problem still happening to me now.